# reactor for the swipe trigger (Experience Toolkit)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to use swipe trigger(provided by Experience Toolkit) in Unity3d. I don't know what should be the reactor. Basically what I want to do is track the user's finger swipe in any of the 4 directions(left, right, up and down). If swiped left, the object should rotate 45 degree in the negative x axis, if swiped right, the object should rotate 45 degree in the positive x axis and so on.

Note: I know, how to do it through a custom script in Unity3d, but I have to do it through Experience Toolkit package as I have to import the .unitypackage in Daqri. As I am new to experience Toolkit, it is possible that I am looking into the wrong trigger for this purpose. So, in that case, I am open for suggestions.